# Acount suspension reason is only shown on the main site profile not meta

Tags: bug, profile-page, account-suspension

I've anonymized the affected user profile, but came across this after seeing a comment on another meta question saying that the reason was visible on the profile; but initially not being able to find it because i was looking at the suspended users meta profile.

[image]

Comment: Still no answer, however.  Maybe there's a better dupe?  I think it's working as intended.

Comment: I don't think it not showing on meta should be working as intended; even if the speculation on the other question is right about it being due to an architectural hack.

Comment: @Dan actually it is [tag:status-bydesign]. Shog9 added a status-bydesign tag to my report of this on MSO: [Suspension not shown properly on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367509/suspension-not-shown-properly-on-meta)